# Python "TypeError: expected string or buffer" with re and csv

Tags: python, csv

So I am working on a program that grabs a Twitter username from a csv file and plugs it into a function that downloads all the tweets. I pretty much have gotten it to work except I think the output of the row from the csv has brackets and apostrophes, `['POTUS']` instead of `POTUS`, which Twitter won't accept.

Here is the code I am using:

```
with open('names.csv') as namescsv:
    namereader = csv.reader(namescsv)
    for row in namereader:
        row = re.sub(r'[^\w=]', '',row)
        print row
```

I used re to try to remove the odd characters, but when I execute the code I get this error:

```
File "/home/ian/Desktop/tweepy_scripts/tweetdownloader_allcsv_v2.py", line 66, in <module>
    row = re.sub(r'[^\w=]', '',row)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Some help would be awesome! I'm a beginner and my attempts to solve the problem using previous articles hasn't yielded much.

Comment: I'm no python expert but the 'r' before your regex looks misplaced

Comment: The `r` is fine. It means "raw" or "regex" string, i.e. it disables `\ ` interpretation.

Comment: I'm guessing `for row in namereader` does not iterate over strings, but rather over objects of some other type

Comment: Just to reduce confusion, you got the `TypeError` because you passed a `list` to the regex, not a string. But the real problem is that you should have pulled a column from this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your row variable is a list, not a string - and Python is warning you that it expects a string.   try something like this:

```
import csv
import re

with open('names.csv') as namescsv:
    namereader = csv.reader(namescsv)
    for row in namereader:
        for cell in row:
            cell = re.sub(r'[^\w=]', '',cell)
            print cell
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think the output of the row from the csv has brackets and apostrophes, `['POTUS']` instead of `POTUS`

No, it doesn't. The output of the row from the csv module is a `list` of `str`s. When you display the list (using, for example, `print`), it is displayed with the punctuation you describe.

Instead of passing `row` off to the Twitter API, you might need to pass a single cell of the row. The first cell is called `row[0]`, so you might need:

```
result = whatever.the.twitter.api.is.called(row[0])
```